# Error: serial device '/dev/ttyAMA0' does not exist

Tags: pi-3, serial

I'm newbie on Raspberry Pi.I have installed serial port using following conmand on raspian l os.

sudo apt-get install python-serial

I'm trying to access serial port communication on Raspberry Pi 3. I have created script using python. When I run the script, I got following error.

```
Error: serial device '/dev/ttyAMA0' does not exist
```

But When I used `/dev/ttyS0`, it's working fine. Why?

My script here.

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600)

while True:
    port.write("Hello world")
    rcv = port.read(10)
    print rcv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **NOT** "installed serial port", although you may have installed `python-serial`

I don't know why you would get `serial device '/dev/ttyAMA0' does not exist`, because it **SHOULD**, although it is connected to Bluetooth, unless you have changed something.

In contrast `/dev/ttyS0` **SHOULD** not exist, because it is disabled by default, again unless you have changed something. (It is possible installing `python-serial` may have done this.)

The only conclusion is that you have executed some other commands, you are not telling us about.

See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) for an explanation.

PS as outlined in the above you now use `/dev/serial0`, which should work on all models.